# OSX: How to have a dedicated application for managing the preferences of another one

Tags: macos, cocoa, preferences

My main application is faceless (no icon in the Dock neither in the menu bar) and I would like to develop another application for managing the preferences.

How can I achieve this (like AlfredApp for the ones who know this app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you could use `NSUserDefaults`'s addSuiteNamed: method. Apple's docs say, about this method:

> The suiteName domain is similar to a bundle identifier string, but is not tied to a particular 
>   application or bundle. A suite can be used to hold preferences that are shared between multiple 
>   applications.

Anyway, this would allow you to write to the NSUserDefaults of that application.

Having said that, using `NSUserDefaults` - or any other method of preference file writing - is going to be restricted if your app is sandboxed (aka: you're writing it for the Mac App Store). So, depending on your goals for the app / distribution method, maybe you should revise your plan.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. (My app is not sandboxed). Thanks!

Comment: You can use -[NSUserDefaults initWithSuiteName:] for setting values in the shared suite